# Backendless - Android: Removing an object from list

Tags: android, list, backendless

I want to remove a user from a List but it seems that it isn't working.
I have a Feeds.class in my project where I have:

```
public class Feeds {
private List<BackendlessUser> usersThatLike;

public List<BackendlessUser> getUsersThatLike() {
return usersThatLike;
}

public void setUsersThatLike(List<BackendlessUser> usersThatLike) {
this.usersThatLike = usersThatLike;
}
}
```

And in my adapter I try to remove the Current user like this:

```
feed.getUsersThatLike().remove(Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser);
```

And than save the Feeds class and in handleResponse I print the list as string in the log window and the current user is still in the list.
Can't figure out what's wrong with it.
Need help.
Thanks

**Adapter**

```
    public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedAdapter.FeedsHolder> {

        private List<Feeds> list;
        private Context context;
        private static List<Long> selectedIds;
        List<BackendlessUser> backendlessUserList;
        private List<Comments> cake = new ArrayList<>();
        private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

        public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<Feeds> list) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;

        }

        @Override
        public FeedsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);

            final FeedsHolder holder = new FeedsHolder(view);

            //Query

            QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();

            options.setRelated(Arrays.asList("usersThatLike"));

            BackendlessDataQuery query = new BackendlessDataQuery();

            query.setQueryOptions(options);

            Backendless.Data.of(Feeds.class).find(query, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Feeds>>() {

                @Override

                public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Feeds> response) {
                    myFeeds = response;
                    String userId = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser().getObjectId();
                    for (Feeds feed : response.getData()) {
                        feed = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                        List<BackendlessUser> likedUsers = feed.getUsersThatLike();
                        backendlessUserList = likedUsers;
                        for (BackendlessUser user : likedUsers)
                            if (user.getObjectId().equals(userId)) {
                                setBackground(holder.like, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
                            } else if (!user.getObjectId().equals(userId)) {
                                setBackground(holder.like, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
                            }
                    }

                }

                @Override

                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

                }

            });
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedsHolder holder, final int position) {
            //Starting Feeds
            final Feeds feeds = list.get(position);

            holder.like.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));

holder.like.setOnClickListener.......
//Skipped for brevity
feeds.getUsersThatLike().remove(Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser);
//SAVE FEEDS HERE
}
}

            //Name
            holder.name.setText(feeds.getOwner());

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public class FeedsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            //Setup Views
            CardView card;
            TextView name;
             ImageView like;

            public FeedsHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                //Assign views by ID
                card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commenter);
                like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked what returns **Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser** ?

Comment: post your full adapter code

Comment: I printed Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser in the log window and it's returning the Current user with all it's properties like name, email, objectId etc... everything formatted like: BackendlessUser{picture: url, name: Asama, objectId: HSKSB1092JSK102J}

Comment: Added Adapter code

Comment: If I use feeds.getUsersThatLike().remove(0); than it's removing the first user who liked the item. What's wrong with the Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser?